# To remove someone's sins

Tags: expressions, idioms, phrasal-verbs

Is there a phrasal verb or an idiom that people use, especially in religious contexts, to wish that God would remove someone's sins? Something like:

- Hassan used to rape girls, but he repented of his evil deeds. I wish that God ***would remove his sins***.

Comment: Another verb that might work and is often used with "sin(s)" is [expiate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expiate). It is not phrasal or an idiom, though. "By doing penance, Hassan was able to expiate the sins of his past."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan That is best written in the answer box. Please avoid answering in the comments section.

Comment: @NVZ OP asked for a phrasal verb or idiom, so I didn't think that it really answered his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Professor John Lawler wrote in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/590977/to-remove-someones-sins#comment1484188_590977):

> The verb is *absolve*, and it takes the forgiver as the subject and forgivee as the object; the reason for the absolution is expressed in a prepositional phrase of some sort. The Catholic Church has a ritual called "confession" that includes the priest saying "I absolve you of your sins" (In Latin, *Ego te absolvo a peccatis tuis*). *Absolve* usually has a human subject, instead of a divine one. With *God* as the subject, we would say *forgive*; absolution is a human sacrament, not an act of God.

Comment: Well, technically, all sacraments are divine; but they have human agents.